# xslt: operations on new elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Could you please explain in case we could perform any operations on newly included elements using xsl?
To explain using an example: if we have the following input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <c>12</c>
        <d>9</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>Yes</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <c>50</c>
        <d>12</d>
    </Results>
</top>
```

We need the final result as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <b_>10</b_>
        <c>12</c>
        <c_>12</c_>
        <d>9</d>
        <e_>11</e_>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>Yes</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <b_>8</b_>
        <c>50</c>
        <c_>50</c_>
        <d>12</d>
        <e_>29</e_>
    </Results>
</top>
```

Where:
b_ = b,
c_ = c,
    &
e_ = (b_ + c_)/2

Comment: If `b = b_` and `c = c_` then `e_ = (b + c) / 2`, no?

Comment: Yes, but this is an example where simple operation generates the elements and further use them for new operations. I want to understand the concept of the use of newly added elements in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stock them into var.

```
<xsl:variable name="b" select="b">
<xsl:variable name="c" select="c">
<a><xsl:value-of select="a"/></a>
<b><xsl:value-of select="b"/></b>
<b_><xsl:value-of select="$b"/></b_>
<c><xsl:value-of select="c"/></c>
<c_><xsl:value-of select="$c"/></c_>
<d><xsl:value-of select="d"/></d>
<e_><xsl:value-of select="($b + $c) div 2"/></e_>
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp).